# Get syntax tree nodes in order of execution using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Is there any way or workaround to get SyntaxTree nodes in order of execution inside file/class using any means of Roslyn. Entry method is known.

Example:

```
class myClass 
{
    void EntryMethod() {
        CallMethod1();
        CallMethod2();
        AnotherMethod();
        CallMethod3();
    }

    void AnotherMethod() 
    {
        CallMethod4();
        CallMethod5();
    }
}
```

Needed result something like:

```
List<ExpressionStatementSyntax or InvocationExpressionSyntax> 
{CallMethod1, CallMethod2, CallMethod4, CallMethod5, CallMethod3}
```

Comment: What if you have loops or if statements? This is equivalent to the Halting Problem.

Comment: @SLaks i think in my case order of appearance inside a method is enough

Comment: Then you can do this yourself with a simple DFS.  Beware of recursion, though.

Comment: What if one of your statements is a call to a method that takes a delegate, and the argument is a lambda, and the lambda contains expressions or statements?  In what order would you like the expressions or statements in the lambda to be enumerated, with respect to the expressions and statements in the method? There is no guarantee about when those expressions will be executed, if ever.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for your comment! I do not need a universal solution for any codebase, codebase that will be analyzed is well-known for me, I am sure that there no any lambda or delegate expressions. My task is to collect all calls of a specific custom method and its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in API for this, as it is in the general case impossible. You can write the code yourself using basic Roslyn APIs though.

Comment: I was trying to do it using basic Roslyn APIs, please check out https://gist.github.com/rchaser/37b03d32a7de4e668203de5069939a26
I think the way i was trying to do it is completly wrong. I know code is not good, but it is draft just to get the main idea